# Can't read html from a webpage 

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get some data (html tags) from a webpage but I just can't. For some reason I just get mainly empty tags.

This is the URL: http://www.miamidade.gov/transit/mobile/routes.asp

This is my java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
class xyz{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc =  jsoup.connect("http://www.miamidade.gov/transit/mobile/routes.asp").userAgent(" Mozilla/5.0").timeout(3000).post();
        String title = doc.html();
        System.out.print(title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The page at http://www.miamidade.gov/transit/mobile/routes.asp first does a javascript redirect to "scriptCheck.asp?script=yes&CurrentPage=/transit/mobile/routes.asp?" . Then it eventually reloads http://www.miamidade.gov/transit/mobile/routes.asp again with the information that you see on the page. Jsoup doesn't seem to handle that redirect, so your code gets the first page and returns with that HTML which is not the same HTML you see when you use a browser. Maybe that is why you don't find the information that you expect.

Source code of the first page

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <title></title> 
  <script language="JavaScript">
<!--
window.location="scriptCheck.asp?script=yes&CurrentPage=/transit/mobile/routes.asp?";
//-->

  </script>
 </head>  
 <body>
  <noscript> 
   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=scriptCheck.asp?script=no&amp;CurrentPage=/transit/mobile/routes.asp?" /> 
  </noscript>  
  <noscript> 
   <br /> 
   <br /> 
   <a href="scriptCheck.asp?script=no&amp;CurrentPage=/transit/mobile/routes.asp?">Enter MDT Mobile Services Site</a> 
   <br /> 
   <br /> 
  </noscript>   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: question: How did you know where the page was direct to?

Comment: how come I don't see the same html code that you see... I am using chrome

Comment: actually that output if the result of the code that you have provided. You do not see it on chrome because the javascript executes and takes the page to another page, scriptCheck.asp. From there it comes back to the original page. You may want to check the sequence of pages through a proxy like http://www.fiddler2.com or through an addon like HttpFox in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("http://www.miamidade.gov/transit/mobile/routes.asp",10000);
System.out.print(doc.toString());
```

May be time out time is not enough for your page

Comment: Yes the way worked for me.Though i didn't test it with your page